# Creating default object from empty value in live project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying update delivered value in database by finding it using its id. I am using same logic for two databases and it is working fine in localhost but in live project it is giving error:

> ErrorException Creating default object from empty value

**Controller.php**

```
    public function toggledeliver(Request $request,$orderId){
        $address=Address::find($orderId);
        if($request->has('delivered')){
            $address->delivered=$request->delivered;
        }else{
            $address->delivered="0";
        }

        $address->save();

        $order=Order::find($orderId);
        if($request->has('delivered')){
            $order->delivered=$request->delivered;
        }else{
            $order->delivered="0";
        }

        $order->save();

        return back();
    }
}
```

**orders.blade.php**

```
    <form action="{{route('toggle.deliver',$order->id)}}" method="POST" class="pull-right">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <label for="delivered">Delivered</label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="delivered" {{$order->delivered==1?"checked":""}}>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: it would be better if you share the db schema for this two table and relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are trying to fetch `address` with `orderId`. Check if `$address` and `$order` empty or not.

```
public function toggledeliver(Request $request,$orderId){

       $address=Address::find($orderId);

       if($address!=null) {
           if($request->has('delivered')){
               $address->delivered=$request->delivered;
           }else{
               $address->delivered="0";
           }

          $address->save();
       }

        $order=Order::find($orderId);

        if($order!=null) {
             if($request->has('delivered')){
                 $order->delivered=$request->delivered;
             }else{
                 $order->delivered="0";
             }

            $order->save();
        }

       return back();
   }
}
```

Try changing this line-

```
$address=Address::find($orderId);
```

To (assuming you have a `order_id` column in `Address` table)-

```
$address=Address::where("order_id",$orderId)->first();
```

Comment: dis you try with my updated code?? is it showing any error??

Comment: !is_null() is giving error. Looks like it is not recognize syntax

Comment: include your full error stack trace in your question please

Comment: 58
ErrorException 
…/app/Http/Controllers/OrderController.php36
57
Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions handleError
…/app/Http/Controllers/OrderController.php36
49
Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing\{closure}
…/app/Http/Middleware/Admin.php23

Comment: make a screenshot and post it

Comment: where is your check?? try with my updated code please. You didn't even add my code. Try with my code and then let me know what happens

Comment: value of order is updated but address value is still not updated.

Comment: is there any error?? what is your address id in db that you want to update?? and what is the value of '$orderId'?? did you have a column name `order_id` in address table??

Comment: Wait a sec looks like I found it

Comment: Actually both table "id" were not matching that is why one table was updated and other was not.

Comment: glad you found it and try to provide information as much as possible like controller code, db schema, relationship between tables, that way others can understand your problem quickly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$address= Address::find($orderId);` returns `NULL`. Add the check:

```
if(!is_null($address) {
   //redirect or show an error message    
}else{
   dd($address);
}
```

Comment: Yes it is returning null

Comment: Please check `orderId`  value

Comment: Order is passing value

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that  `$order=Order::find($orderId);` returns `null`.

**Add the check:**

```
  if(!is_null($address)) {
   $address=Address::find($orderId);
    if($request->has('delivered')){
        $address->delivered=$request->delivered;
    }else{
        $address->delivered="0";
    }

    $address->save();
    } else {
    //order_id was null, 
   //do stuff
     }

    if(!is_null($order)) {
            if($request->has('delivered')){
                $order->delivered=$request->delivered;
            }else{
                $order->delivered="0";
            }

            $order->save();

            return back();
    } else {
    //order_id was null, 
   //do stuff
     }
```

Comment: You could do the same for address then!

Comment: @Faiez I have updated my answer. Please check if it works

Comment: !is_null() is giving error. Looks like it is not recognize syntax. But i am using empty and still sam error

Comment: @Faiez I'm sorry I had missed a `)` please check now

Comment: ErrorException Creating default object from empty value

Answer (score 0):

This means there is no address with `ID = $orderId`. You can add the check:

```
if (empty($address))
```

Also, you could use `findOrNew()` if you want to create a new address if it doesn't exist:

```
$address = Address::findOrNew($orderId);
```

If you want to find address by order ID, you should use relationship:

```
$address = Order::find($orderId)->address
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the address with the given ID doesn't exist in database. You can use *findOrFail* method. This method will throw a 404 - not found exception if no data is found.

```
$model = App\Flight::findOrFail(1);
```

Or

You can check if the result array is empty.

```
if (empty($model)){
  // code
}
```